# How to extract a number from a column with words and numbers in postgresql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, sql-like

I am trying to write a query in Postgresql where I need to extract the order number from a details column but I only want to extract the order number if the entry in the column contains "Used as payment on order x", with x being the number I need to extract. I'm not sure how to do this since the order numbers contain varying numbers of digits. Here is what I have so far-

Example string- "Used as payment on order 1034267"
Desired output- 1034267

Example string- "Used as payment on order 55263"
Desired output- 55263

```
SELECT details
FROM transactions
WHERE details LIKE 'Used as payment on order%'
```

But this gets the whole column entry and not just the number. How can I grab just the number from an entry?

Comment: Add some sample string and your expected output from them.

Comment: Is it possible that the text contains any other number? Or can you be 100% that any number found is the one you are looking for?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the text will only contain one number, so I can be 100% positive that the number found is the number I need

Comment: @mkRabbani Just added some samples/what the desired output is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be one using `regexp_replace()` and removing everything that is not a digit from the input string:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(details, '[^0-9]+', '', 'g')
FROM transactions
WHERE details LIKE 'Used as payment on order%'
```